# Can you help me understand this?

Tags: geometry, ratio

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYOjj.jpg]
>
> The diagram shows
>
> - A cylinder inside a cone on a horizontal base.
> - The cone and cylinder have the same vertical axis
> - The base of the cylinder lies on the base of the cone
> - The circumference of the top face of the cylinder touches the curved surface of the cone
>
> The cylinder has radius $r$ cm and volume $V$ cm$^3$.
>
> Show that $$V=12\pi r^2-3\pi r^3$$

This question is from the IGCSE Edexcel 2016 3HR exam.
I have tried many times to solve it, then I looked up the answer and I couldn't understand it.
I even searched for solutions online, but could not find any help.

Comment: Post here this problem and show your attempts.

Comment: @ Hint draw a 2-d figure and use similar triangles ratio property

Comment: I have typed out your images using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). In future please only post images of diagrams, not of text. Not everyone on the site can see images (because of poor internet or use of screen readers) and also images are not searchable so less people will see your question

Comment: Sorry. I will take this to consideration next time.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to consider similar triangles. Let the height of the cylinder by $h$. Then $\frac{12}{h}=\frac{4}{4-r}$. This way you'll find $h$ in terms of $r$. You get that $h=12-3r$. Now you just have to simplify $V=\pi r^2 h$.